# cartographer - undefined method 'has_key?'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a problem with Cartographer plugin for rails3:
https://github.com/joshuamiller/cartographer

I've done everything just like in the docs and all i'm getting is this  error: `undefined method 'has_key?' for false:FalseClass` in this line:

```
<% raw Cartographer::Header.new.to_s %>
```

Has anyone any idea what am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved - i was using rails `3.0.3` and after changing it to `3.0.1` everything works fine.